# Matplotlib Colorbar Scaling

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I have a plot that I artificially saturate and would like the colorbar to reflect this. My current code saturates the image fine, but the colorbar still shows the saturated values. I would like the colorbar to stop at the maximum value that is still plotted, maybe indicated by an arrow (I have seen the 'extend' keyword for this but haven't been able to apply it).

This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,x)

z = np.exp(-(x**2+y**2))
plt.contourf(x,y,z,100,vmax=.75*np.max(z))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

What can I do to

1. Cut off the colorbar
2. Indicate the fact that it is cut by topping the colorbar off with an arrow instead of the regular box shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting a contour plot. This means you get the colors of the levels in the colorbar. The `extend` keyword to colorbar does not make much sense for such plot, since there are no colors outside of any range to be shown.

You may of course set the levels, such that the last level comprises of "the rest of the range". Then you may use the `extend` keyword for `contourf`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,x)

z = np.exp(-(x**2+y**2))

levels = np.linspace(z.min(),0.75*z.max(),100)
levels[-1] = z.max()
plt.contourf(x,y,z,levels, extend="both", vmax=0.75*z.max())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

It seems in this case a more reasonable way to plot the data (which is dense enough anyways) is to use a `pcolormesh` plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,x)

z = np.exp(-(x**2+y**2))

plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z, vmax=0.75*z.max())
plt.colorbar(extend="both")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is the behaviour I want. The actual data looks quite different, I just generated this for a MWE.

> The extend keyword does not make much sense for such plot, since there are no colors outside of any range to be shown.

I manually changed the colorbar to be saturated at 0.75*max though. I simply do not see how this differs from the "extend" keyword for the pcolormesh plot.

I also have an issue with saving the pcolormesh, neither through the opened figure and matplotlib GUI nor with savefig it works. Python just crashes.

Comment: Since I could not find how to edit my comment:
I have tried the savefig() command on a computer with bigger memory and that works. The generated file (eps) is huge though. Compared to the contourplot it is more than 20 times the size. Is this intended behaviour? Especially when invoking it in a pdf I am scared of abysmal load times when viewing the file on the computer.

Comment: Contourf and pcolormesh are fundamentally different. But maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve. In any case I updated the answer, such that the contourf plot also has the little triangles.